# Зимой - наречие или существительное?

Tags: наречия, части-речи, существительные

[Есть такое правило](https://kak-pravilno.net/zimoy-ili-zimoyu-kak-pravilno/)

```
Если у слова «зимой» есть зависимые слова (ранней зимой, этой зимой), то это существительное: 
Ранней зимой снег долго не лежит.
Этой зимой первый снег выпал очень рано.
```

[С другой стороны](https://www.google.ru/books/edition/%D0%96%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%9C_%D0%92/aQ2jAAAAQBAJ?hl=ru&gbpv=1&dq=%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&pg=PT776&printsec=frontcover)

```
Приехал ранней зимой. Зимой - существительное, так как определено прилагательным.
Приехал рано зимой. Зимой - наречие, так как только при наречии (не при существительном) может быть пояснительное наречие на -о.
Приехал зимой. Здесь зимой столько же наречие, сколько существительное. Фифти-фифти.
```

А как тогда трактовать **зимой** в таком предложении?

```
Приехал рано снежной зимой.
```

Comment: Словосочетания  «рано зимой / поздно зимой» существуют? Не заменить ли на **рано утром**?

Comment: А вы верите этому правилу? Насколько оно авторитетно? Допустил бы примыкание прилагательного к наречию, так как у него форма существительного. Это логичнее. Во всех примерах вопрос *когда?*, а не существительного.